# pdfpages, wrongly inserted pdf

Tags: xetex, two-column, pdfpages

I need to include several PDF into my document. For that, i use pdfpages. But there is a problem: The PDF doesn't start after the content, instead it starts immediately and is overlaid with parts of document content.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[twocolumn, 10pt, twoside=true, open=any, a4paper, BCOR=10mm, DIV=15, pagesize=auto, headings=normal, chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Test}
    \section{Test sec}
    Hello!
    
    \includepdf[pages={1-}]{paper/1.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question the right way. You'd like to include a PDF, but without breaking your text? Text should run until the end of the page, then the PDF, and then on with your text?

Comment: Yes, this is what i am aiming for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble comes from the option `twocolumn`. If you want to insert a PDF, switch back to onecolumn. If you need twocolumn layout, use the multicol package, you get the manual with `texdoc multicol` on the command line. Beware, the environment is calle `multicols`, mind the "s".

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track., i can even work around it by setting \onecolum before and \twocolumn after the pdfinclude. Maybe this should be reported as a bug.